# Webcam not recognized on Debian 11/sid

Tags: debian, camera

My webcam is there, physically, but it is not recognized *anywhere* in my computer. The only place I see anything related to video is in `# dmesg | grep video`:

```
[   64.907469] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   64.921610] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   72.665592] usbcore: deregistering interface driver uvcvideo
[   72.848476] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   72.857832] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
```

Some other possibly useful commands are `lsusb`:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 093a:2533 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Gaming Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1b3f:2008 Generalplus Technology Inc. USB Audio Device
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And `lsmod | grep video`

```
uvcvideo              114688  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         36864  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       65536  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              286720  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
mc                     61440  5 videodev,snd_usb_audio,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
usbcore               323584  6 xhci_hcd,snd_usb_audio,usbhid,snd_usbmidi_lib,uvcvideo,xhci_pci
usb_common             16384  3 xhci_hcd,usbcore,uvcvideo
video                  53248  1 asus_wmi
```

`ls /dev/video*`:

```
zsh: no matches found: /dev/video*
```

I know there is a similar question aleady on StackExchange but their solution **does not work**, my laptop does *not* have a webcam button.

My laptop is an ASUS TUF Gaming FX705DY running Linux 5.10.0-5-amd64 x86_64

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem: the USB enumeration was ok (even the device for the microphone in the webcam was created) but no `/dev/video` and `cheese` reported `no device found`.

I took a look to `dmesg` and found it was reporting a problem with a firmware not related to the webcam (`firmware: failed to load rtl_nic/rtl8168h-2.fw`). To fix it, I added `contrib` and `non-free` to `deb` line in `/etc/apt/source.list` and then:

```
apt update
apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
apt install firmware-linux firmware-realtek
```

I rebooted - but along the way I also enabled in BIOS "xHCI hand-off" - and `cheese` was working.

That is, I can't tell which change made the trick, but maybe it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
device="/dev/whatever"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, but there is one more step.

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.

Comment: what's the device? `/dev/video?`? It's not there. I probably should have put that info in the post.