# Integrated camera stopped working/being detected on Debian 11 Lenovo thinkpad 4th gen

Tags: debian, thinkpad, camera

I have a lenovo thinkpad X1 carbon 4th gen that was working fine for several years, on Debian 11, but the integrated camera suddenly stopped working. It is enabled in the bios, just not detected anymore on my machine.

I've been looking for answers for a couple of weeks now but nothing I found seems to work. If anyone has tips were to look for, I'd highly appreciate!
Thanks in advance!

Here some of the outcomes of different commands:

```
$guvcview
GUVCVIEW: version 2.0.6
V4L2_CORE: ERROR opening V4L interface: No such file or directory
GUVCVIEW (1): Guvcview error
         no video device found
```

```
$lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye
```

```
$uname -r
5.10.0-21-amd64
```

```
$lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 138a:0090 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS7500 Touch Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1199:9079 Sierra Wireless, Inc. EM7455
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8152 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8152 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
$lsmod | grep video
video                  61440  2 thinkpad_acpi,i915
```

```
$ls /dev/video*
ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory
```

EDIT

Thanks @Peregrino69 for your help!

Ultimately I reinstalled completely Debian and... still not working. I think it's a firmware issue, because I imagine that if I reinstall the OS, the modules should automatically be installed, right? Otherwise, linked to your last comment: how can I find out which driver module is need for my camera? On Lenovo website for my model I find only Windows or Mac ones. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe it's just broken? If you boot into a Live OS, does it show up?

Comment: Thanks @Peregrino69 good idea. I tried that, I booted on a live debian and tested my camera online... Still not detected. Maybe indeed it's just broken, though I am not sure how it broke. Do you think it could be a missing firmware, or should I just accept defeat? Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's what one calls great timing! I was just browsing through RasPi site, and literally at the same time you made the comment bumped into this: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/77768/error-opening-v4l-interface-no-such-file-or-directory :-D

Comment: Friend, don't put answers in comments, [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/739620/edit) your question instead to add any new info to keep it up-to-date and everything relevant easily available :-) Please do that, and we can delete these then-unnecessary comments - the comment space is limited, as this isn't intended for discussions. I don't actually know as I never used mine... an interesting question, I'll see if I can figure out how you can figure it out :-)

Comment: Check `dmesg | grep -i video`. That should show you quite a lot about the device, including the driver if its' loading. E.g. mine shows `uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HD WebCam (04f2:b571)` and `usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo`, which means my cam's supported by the [kernel UVC driver](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.9/media/v4l-drivers/uvcvideo.html). It should also show any related errors. Someone has resolved similar issue with Deb11 by correcting seemingly unrelated FW error: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/653540/webcam-not-recognized-on-debian-11-sid